# how to use personal_sign

Tags: transactions, signature

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs

> {"method": "personal_sign", "params": [message, account, password]}

The param message is a hex string, how can I generate it from a tx?

What I want to ask is, if I have a tx, for example: `{from:0x1234,to:0x4321,value:xxxx,gas:xxx,gasPrice:xxxx}`

How can I generate the message?

I try to find a sample of it but got nothing.
Hope someone can give an example.
Very thanks.

Comment: Actually, try using `eth_signTypedData`

Answer (score 5):

You can use personal_sign as following:

```
import Web3 from 'web3';
web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);

web3.personal.sign(web3.toHex("message to sign"), "from_address", function(err, 
signature) {
      console.log('signature: ' + signature);
}
```

When the MetaMask app is installed in the user's browser and logged in, the MetaMask will pop up the sign window, which looks like:

[image]

The signature looks like 
0x206xxxxxxxxxx18f47ec659e12531f47c22d8402378c697f1ae18b22bbe4610702c95c35f5098141fd3c54a9e9f4eb80b21b6d692bfb3f6e05008fc06af9c2201b
(just x-ed a couple of characters..)

Comment: how to verify the signature?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work for you:

```
var ethUtil = require('ethereumjs-util');
var ethereumjs = require('ethereumjs-abi);

const nonce = 0;
const message = ethereumjs.soliditySHA3(           
    ["address", "address", "uint", "uint", "uint", "uint"],
    [from, to, amount, gas, gasPrice, nonce]
);

{"method": "personal_sign", "params": [ethUtil.bufferToHex(new Buffer(message, 'utf8')), account, password]}
```

However, the prompt from MetaMask looks ugly since the message it displays is coming from binary data.  I'm still wondering how to fix that.

Comment: Did you managed how to change the message?